# Converter valor para exibir na tabela - mvc asp-net.core

Tags: razor, asp.net-core

Tenho uma tabela que ela me trás um valor em `int` e preciso converter este valor pra hora, como posso realizar este procedimento, no caso precisaria criar uma função pra me mostrar o valor correto.

```
<td>
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HoraInicio)
</td>
```

Nesta parte eu preciso pegar o valor `item.HoraInicio` e realizar uma conversão, porém ele não me deixa declarar variáveis para realizar a mudança, como posso fazer?

Comment: Utilizo page-razor, as views próprias criadas.

Comment: Sim, eu consegui mudar outros valores, utilizando if, porém pensei em algo como @(int valor), porém ele não reconhece.

Comment: Se grava a hora em inteiro no banco?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma opção é abrir um bloco de código, ficaria assim:

```
<td>
    @{ 
        var horario = item.HoraInicio;
        //logica
    }
    <label>@horario</label>
</td>
```

Outra opção é ter um campo no seu modelo que já traga a informação como deseja

```
public class Horario
{
    public int HoraInicio { get; set; }

    public string HoraExibicao
    {
        get
        {
            //Logica
            return HoraInicio.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

e na sua página

```
<td>
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HoraExibicao)
</td>
```

Comment: A minha lógica estava certo, o problema tava aonde eu estava abrindo o bloco de código. Obrigado mais uma vez. Fiz igual me informou e deu certo.